# Targeting inner directories within a .jar file -- java

Tags: java, wsdl

I have a web service client which works perfectly fine, within which there is a line that defines the location of the WSDL:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "CReceiveMOMessageService", 
                  targetNamespace = "http://...", 
                  wsdlLocation = "CReceiveMOMessageService.wsdl")
```

The code piece should be exported as a runnable JAR and is intended to work on a remote location.

When I define the location of the WSDL as above, it looks for a WSDL file at the directory in which I run the JAR file. Instead what I would like to do is to add the WSDL file to the project folder and export as JAR after that, and configure `wsdlLocation` parameter in a way that it points to the WSDL within the JAR file.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to add the WSDL to the JAR. It seems that the convention is to place the WSDL in the JAR at the `META-INF/wsdl` location (although Oracle tools seem to favor `META-INF/wsdls` (see [point 9 of this Oracle tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/jaxwsclienttutorial-2-095181.html) for example).

I haven't used the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse and I guess the OEPE ClientGen task does the correct generation of the client classes when you specify to package the WSDL inside the JAR but I don't think it's the same as passing a `-wsdllocation META-INF/wsdls/YourService.wsdl` parameter when running [`wsimport.exe`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html):

`wsimport.exe` will output `@WebServiceClient(... wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdls/YourService.wsdl")` but will also normally generate code like this in the static initializer of the class:

```
baseUrl = YourService.class.getResource(".");
url = new URL(baseUrl, "META-INF/wsdls/YourService.wsdl");
```

which will still point to a root folder to which it then adds the provided WSDL path to finally get a non existent path.

You will have to change the class after it's generated to include something like this instead:

```
url = YourService.class.getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/wsdls/YourService.wsdl");
```

which will now point within the JAR. Off course you must pack the WSDL at that location when building the client JAR.